# Iterate through JSON and change arrays to strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a JSON object that was returned from an XML to js function. This xml converter creates arrays for every entry even when they should be strings. I cannot modify this original function so therefore I would like to take my final json object, iterate through it, detect if a value is an array of length 1 and, if so, change that array to a string.

Original object:

```
var json = {
  user: {
     name: ["bob"],
     email: ["bob@example.org"]
  },
  items: [{ 
    name: ["Object 1"]
  },{ 
    name: ["Object 2"]
  }]
}
```

Should become:

```
var json = {
  user: {
     name: "bob",
     email: "bob@example.org"
  },
  items: [{ 
    name: "Object 1"
  },{ 
    name: "Object 2"
  }]
}
```

I have considered the reviver function but a) I would like to avoid going back to a string and b) I am not sure if that would even work as it will probably just feed me each array element individually.

Comment: This is tough because it has to be recursive. I feel like you should just handle the case when it comes about, with a simple check `if ($.isArray(val) && val.length == 1) {...}`. Either that or have the backend programmer return what you need, without you having to modify it.

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of this stuff, it's worth noting that [lodash](http://lodash.com/) is an excellent library.

Comment: @BenjaminRH are you saying lodash has just this function? or are you suggesting one of the recurse functions and apply my own filters?

Comment: It doesn't have a function that solves this specific case, I just meant that it has a lot of useful functions for iterating and manipulating arrays and objects, such as `_.forEach`, `_.isObject`, and `_.isArray`

Comment: @Yashua For instance, here's the accepted answer, using lodash: http://jsfiddle.net/YnFyS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive function seems to work for this problem:

```
function simplify(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[k]) == '[object Array]' && obj[k].length == 1) {
            obj[k] = obj[k][0];
        }
        else if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') {
            obj[k] = simplify(obj[k]);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

simplify(json);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xkz4W/

Comment: Almost - I needed to add `obj[k] = simplify(obj[k]);` on the first if as well - my example was not as complex as my real stuff which had some depth recursion issues. If you would please edit answer...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive way to do it:

```
function flattenArrays(data) {

    function processItem(item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            if (item.length === 1 && typeof item[0] === "string") {
                data[prop] = item[0];
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                    processItem(item[i]);
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof item === "object") {
            flattenArrays(item);
        }
    }

    for (var prop in data) {
        processItem(data[prop]);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/L5WKs/